# jQuery tabs "add" method creates two <div> elements

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

I'm frustrated by the fact that the "add" method in jQuery's tabs ui is adding an extra tab-panel div to my "#tabs" element. This is the line of code I'm using to add a tab showing a calendar that gets its content via Ajax:

```
$("#tabs").tabs("add", "tabContent.php?id=48&tab=calendar", "Calendar");
```

Initially there was only one tab and now there should be two. Indeed, two tabs now exist in the `<ul>` element, but there are mysteriously now three `<div>` elements corresponding to tab panels as shown below. This wouldn't be a problem if not for the fact that one of the newly created `<div>` elements is not hidden even though it corresponds to an inactive tab. As a result, the `<div>`, though empty, takes up a block of space at the bottom of my first and original tab panel. Sorry for the cluttered code, but I included all the raw jQuery markup to show exactly what jQuery did.

```
<div id="tabs" class="ui-tabs ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
    <ul class="ui-tabs-nav ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">
        <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-selected ui-state-active"><a href="#tabs-1">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top"><a href="#ui-tabs-2"><span>Calendar</span></a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom">
            Original Tab
    </div>

    <!-- Why are there two divs here?? -->
    <!-- Note that first <div> below not given class 'ui-tabs-hide' -->
    <div id="ui-tabs-2" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom"></div>
    <div id="ui-tabs-1" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom ui-tabs-hide"></div>
</div>
```

Notice the two `<div>` elements at the bottom where there should only be one.

Comment: Please include more code, eps the part you initiate the tabs.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem. I use AJAX tabs too.

So i looked in the source code of JQuery UI.

Function `add` creates this extra div, but then function `_tabify` is called, and it creates extra div with no 'ui-tabs-hide' class. I think, it creates extra div because it can not find the first one.

Both functions use `_tabId` to get the id of the new tab, and it uses `u()` function to get the index of the tab.

The reason it doesn't work is that `u()` is called twice, in add and in tabify functions.

But `u()` uses variable `v` this way: `++v`, so it gives you the index and adds 1.

So in the `add` function div with id 'ui-tabs-1' is created, but in tabify you get another id = 'ui-tabs-2', can not find it and another div is created.

I tried this: added `if(!b)v--` before second call of _tabId: `i=a._tabId(f);`. It's in `_tabify` function.

Var b is true when tabs are created, and false when you add new tab. Theres one more function that calls _tabify with b=false, it's _setOption. But I don't know if this added code ruins it or not.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. Have you made any progress?

**EDIT:  SEE http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/5069

**

```
$('#tabs').tabs('add', '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/tmijsp/mockups/engineTestContainer.jsp' , 'Engine Test' );
```

I add my tab (this is for mockup purposes)... and I get the same mysterious tab in the container. 
I also try to remove all the tabs before creating new ones through :

```
for (var i = number - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        alert('removing ' + i);
        $('#tabs').tabs('remove', i);
        alert('removed ' + i);
    }
```

This loop seems to identify the non-mysterious tabs, but it doesn't see the mysterious ones. ...

so if I add 1 tab, 2 get created
I remove all from the tab list via loop.. it identifies the 1... and the mysterious divs do not get deleted.

if I go and re-add say.. 2 more tabs, 4 get created.
when I remove them.. the 2 displayed get removed, good... but the mystery divs do not.

The display and functionality is fine.. all except that I have this ever enlarging container of mystery hidden divs.. which grows the tabs vertically on the page.